# Best way to join table with million rows

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables with more rows.

1. table `FIRM` with `500.000 rows`;
2. table `FURNISHER` with `1.000.000 rows`;

Each row of both tables has a `PRIMARY id`.

**Each FIRM row should be merged with approximately 10000 rows of FURNISHER.**

For example:

`FIRM.id` = 3 has this `FURNISHER.ids (5,23,67,456,123, ....)`

`FIRM.id` = 7 has this `FURNISHER.ids (6,23,1200, ....)`

...

What is the best way to save the `FURNISHER ids` assigned to `FIRM`?

I need to create an additional table that only holds the `relationships` between `FIRM` and `FURNISHER` tables?

If I create a new table how should it be?

```
CREATE TABLE `firm_relation` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `firm_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `furnisher_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;



ALTER TABLE `firm_relation`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `rel` (`firm_id`,`furnisher_id`);


ALTER TABLE `firm_relation`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

So I would have about 500.000 x 10.000 rows...